# identify 2 sci fi books "clothespin drop for honesty " and "spaceship with AI named Gay"

Tags: story-identification, space, artificial-intelligence

Looking for 2 books. One is perhaps 20 to 30 years old. Small group travel instantly via a ship with Artificial intelligence they have name Gay. I think it might have been able to traverse time or alternate dimensions.

Second book I read as a teen early 60s. Older teen or young adult trying to get into space academy. One of the entrance exams involves seeing how many clothespins [I think ] he can drop into a milk bottle while blind folded. Turns out to be a test for honesty.

Comment: If you would, please separate this into two questions.

Comment: On a side note, even adding "science fiction" to the query, you get a lot of scary results when you search for "clothespin" and "test" on Google...

Comment: The second one sounds like 'Space Cadet'. alsp by Heinlein.

Comment: @sueelleker is correct.

Comment: This is why we need to separate questions...

Comment: Apologies for the vague combined queries. That was about all I could remember.  I've looked up plot lines for Space Cadet And Number of the Beast and think these are the two I'm looking for. Less certain about space cadet but will read it and look for honor test. Thanks.

Comment: It's definitely Space Cadet. It was beans in a dark room not clothespins blindfolded.

Answer (score 12):

The first one is likely Robert Heinlein's *[The Number of the Beast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_of_the_Beast_%28novel%29)*. The car in question is named *Gay Deceiver*, has an artificial intelligence, and is equipped with the professor's "continua" device which lets them travel to alternate realities.

[image: Cover image]